# Django 403 Forbidden permission error on Linode even after assigning correct permission to all files in Apache2

Tags: python, django, server, permissions, apache2

I was trying to host my Django website on Linode. This is how my project hierarchy is. I haven't touched my etc/apache2/apache2.conf file.

```
/
-->root
    |-->Intranet(Project folder)
            |-->Intranet
                    |-->wsgi.py
```

Even after granting all the necessary permission I am getting a 403 permission error. Where am I going wrong with the configuration files?

My **000-default.conf** file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Alias /static /root/Intranet/static
        <Directory /root/Intranet/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /root/Intranet/media
        <Directory /root/Intranet/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /root/Intranet/Intranet>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /root/Intranet/Intranet/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess intranet python-path=/root/Intranet python-home=/root
        WSGIProcessGroup intranet

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This is what I ran after editing the 000 conf file.

```
chmod 664 Intranet/db.sqlite3
chown :www-data Intranet/db.sqlite3
chown :www-data Intranet
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Why am I still getting the error?

### Edit

The `journalctl | tail` says :

```
Oct 25 05:45:23 localhost sshd[5392]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Oct 25 05:45:23 localhost sshd[5392]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=118.141.208.166
Oct 25 05:45:25 localhost sshd[5390]: Failed password for invalid user pi from 118.141.208.166 port 45496 ssh2
Oct 25 05:45:25 localhost sshd[5390]: Connection closed by invalid user pi 118.141.208.166 port 45496 [preauth]
Oct 25 05:45:25 localhost sshd[5392]: Failed password for invalid user pi from 118.141.208.166 port 45498 ssh2
Oct 25 05:45:25 localhost sshd[5392]: Connection closed by invalid user pi 118.141.208.166 port 45498 [preauth]
Oct 25 05:47:53 localhost sshd[5543]: Accepted password for root from 157.45.252.91 port 20247 ssh2
Oct 25 05:47:53 localhost sshd[5543]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 25 05:47:53 localhost systemd[1]: Started Session 3422 of user root.
Oct 25 05:47:53 localhost systemd-logind[552]: New session 3422 of user root.
```

### Edit 2

After doing some more research. I tried implementing. This is what I am getting now

```
Oct 25 06:20:52 localhost sshd[7720]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.72  user=root
Oct 25 06:20:58 localhost sudo[7830]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
Oct 25 06:20:58 localhost sudo[7830]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
Oct 25 06:20:58 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 25 06:20:58 localhost apachectl[7836]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Oct 25 06:21:08 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 25 06:21:08 localhost systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 25 06:21:08 localhost apachectl[7841]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Oct 25 06:21:08 localhost systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 25 06:21:08 localhost sudo[7830]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

### Edit 3

My Apache error log says

```
[Fri Oct 25 06:25:01.807836 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 7858:tid 140346799950784] AH00489: Apache/2.4$[Fri Oct 25 06:25:01.807859 2019] [core:notice] [pid 7858:tid 140346799950784] AH00094: Command line: '$ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site
```

Comment: Please do not add questions featuring live links. The detail of the question *must* go in the question itself. This ensures that the question shall still be useful to other readers even after you have fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer can you please hel me with it, I am having a hard time finding solution for this

Comment: Have a look at your `error.log` to see what the file-level errors actually are.

Comment: What did you find when you researched the new errors you found? It looks like you are running SSHFS and it is trying to use a user that does not exist. A user of `pi` might be appropriate for a Raspberry Pi, but it would be unusual on Linode, I would guess.

Comment: Its my linode system where I am trying to host the website.

Comment: I don't think that is an answer to the question I have asked. Are you running SSHFS? I want to encourage you to _read_ the errors you've posted, and to respond to what they are saying. "Failed password" means something. Can you research this using a search engine?

Comment: (By the way, do check that you have retrieved the errors from the right SSH session. If you are signed into your local Raspberry Pi instead of your remote Linode server then you will be pasting the wrong errors).

Comment: There is no sign of raspberry pi here. Its just my windows machine with WSl and the linode system

Comment: OK. Maybe log a ticket with Linode support then - perhaps there is an issue with the way they have configured a file system volume.

Comment: @halfer http://172.105.36.26/ this is what I am getting now, please check the updated question for logs

Comment: Have you checked your Apache logs specifically? They are likely to be in `/var/log/apache/error.log` or similar. I wonder if the `journal` is getting you irrelevant errors about your SSH activity.

Comment: @halfer please check I have updated. Moreover I am not using any virtual environment for my django project

Comment: I would say "No module named site" is probably worth investigation. Have you searched for this error on the web?

Comment: Yes I did, but nothing is working out because all the solutions are related to virtual environment which I am not using