# Django Internal Server Error when accessing the website

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2, wsgi

I have hosted my Django website on a Linux machine. I have also granted all the required permissions to my project directory. But when I am trying to access the website from my browser I am getting an error

```
    Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at li1988-26.members.linode.com Port 80
```

on the page.

This is my project structure

```
/var/www/Intranet/

├── db.sqlite3
├── Intranet
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── mainapp
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   └── mainapp
│   │       ├── css
│   │       │   └── base.css
│   │       └── js
│   │           └── base.js
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── mainapp
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       └── homepage.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── users
│       └── images
│           └── default.jpg
├── static
│   ├── admin
│   └── mainapp
│       ├── css
│       │   └── base.css
│       └── js
│           └── base.js
└── users
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── static
    ├── templates
    │   └── users
    │       ├── change_password.html
    │       ├── login.html
    │       ├── logout.html
    │       ├── password_change_done.html
    │       ├── password_reset_complete.html
    │       ├── password_reset_confirm.html
    │       ├── password_reset_done.html
    │       └── password_reset.html
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName li1988-26.members.linode.com

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/var/www/Intranet
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Intranet/Intranet/wsgi.py

Alias /robots.txt /var/www/Intranet/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/Intranet/static/favicon.ico
Alias /static/ /var/www/Intranet/static/
Alias /static/ /var/www/Intranet/media/

<Directory /var/www/Intranet/Intranet>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/Intranet/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/Intranet/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And then I issued the commands

```
a2ensite 000-default.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The error log `nano /var/log/apache2/error.log` says

```
[Fri Oct 25 09:12:51.993097 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16523:tid 140088200727488] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 25 09:12:51.993178 2019] [core:notice] [pid 16523:tid 140088200727488] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Oct 25 09:18:42.041782 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16523:tid 140088200727488] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Oct 25 09:18:42.063081 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16523:tid 140088200727488] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 25 09:18:42.063104 2019] [core:notice] [pid 16523:tid 140088200727488] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Oct 25 09:22:13.165844 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16523:tid 140088200727488] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Oct 25 09:22:13.359270 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16523:tid 140088200727488] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 25 09:22:13.359309 2019] [core:notice] [pid 16523:tid 140088200727488] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Oct 25 09:22:48.864610 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16523:tid 140088200727488] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
```

I have tried all the solutions that I was getting as suggestion to this question but none of them worked for me.

**EDIT 2 : Update Apache error log**

```
   [Sat Oct 26 06:25:02.373002 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 22161:tid 139856591948736] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mo$[Sat Oct 26 06:25:02.373042 2019] [core:notice] [pid 22161:tid 139856591948736] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apach$
   [Sat Oct 26 19:46:25.042037 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 22161:tid 139856591948736] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting $
   [Sat Oct 26 19:46:25.116742 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 25602:tid 140008539728832] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mo$
   [Sat Oct 26 19:46:25.116818 2019] [core:notice] [pid 25602:tid 140008539728832] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apach$
```

Comment: This appears to be a repost of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547297/django-403-forbidden-permission-error-on-linode-even-after-assigning-correct-per). I have, again, removed the live site links that are not appropriate for a long-term Q&A.

Comment: in order to help you we need the error log for apache2, your settings.py and the full structure of your project .

Comment: @FarhaniWalid http://li1988-26.members.linode.com/ please check I have updated everything

Comment: Do you have created a virtualenv when you have developed your project ?

Comment: No I haven't used virtual env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After troubleshooting the issue together, it was the mod_wsgi that wasn't installed properly. just for future references

Comment: Its still showing the same error!!! check it out here http://li1988-26.members.linode.com/

Comment: I am editing the file `sites-available/000-default.conf` . Do you want me tod edit `/etc/apache2/apache.config` Previously when I used to host my website I have never edited the apache.config file. i used to edit 000-default config file and it used to work. Can you tell me when do we edit the apache config file please

Comment: no you don't have to edit the apache config...when you run python3 manage.py runserver what do you get ?

Comment: ```October 26, 2019 - 19:43:23
Django version 2.2.6, using settings 'Intranet.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.```

Comment: can you please add the /var/log/apache2/error.log just after you get the Internal Server Error message

Comment: from the log there is no error which something that is not correct, when you run sudo apache2ctl configtest what do you have ?

Comment: I am getting `Syntax OK`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201457/discussion-between-farhani-walid-and-himanshu-poddar).